# R: How to merge objects to a table?

Tags: r, read.table

How can you actually create a table out of objects? Imagine the following three objects:

```
green<-10
red<- 12
blue<-5
```

How can you combine them to a table that would then look as follows:

```
table1<-read.table(header = TRUE, text = 
"green red blue
10 12 5")
```

Any ideas? Thank you so much!

Comment: This looks more like a list: `list(green=10, red=12, blue=5)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would to get the objects in a `list` and convert to `data.frame`.

```
data.frame(mget(c('green', 'red', 'blue')))
```

Comment: ! Super fast and reliable. Indeed that works perfectly! Thanks so much!